# how to access internal properties from java test code

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin

I've got some class with property marked as internal. 
Then I try to set that property from test code which is in java. 
How can I access those properties? test code and class code are in the same package.

example:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    interal var someProperty = "test"
}
```

test code:

```
@Test
public void firstStartTest() {
    val activity = MainActivity() 
    activity.setSomeProperty("something") //does not compile

}
```

Android Studio is suggesting activity.setSomeProperty$production_sources_for_module_app();
but this also does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add @JvmField annotation.
It treats variable as java protected

Answer (score 1):

Both classes (MainActivity and test class) must be in one module. This is a module definition:

> More specifically, a module is a set of Kotlin files compiled together:
>
> - an IntelliJ IDEA module;
> - a Maven or Gradle project;
> - a set of files
>     compiled with one invocation of the Ant task.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html

It means, check your project structure.

Comment: I have it in same gradle project. Classes are in \app\src\main\kotlin\pl\orendi\bit\MainActivity.kt and test are in \app\src\androidTest\java\pl\orendi\bit\Test.java
I've used package fields to do field injection and is it possible with kotlin?

Comment: Try to create a same test as Kotlin class. Because I didn't find anything exactly described an access of internal Kotlin properties from Java code, assume should be same as from Kotlin code, but may be not.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this:

- Make the property `protected`. Note on how Java & Kotlin treat `protected` differently. In Java it's possible that other classes in the same package access `protected` members. Thus your test class (in Java) can access it.
- Access the property via its ugly name. It should be sort of like `activity.setSomeProperty$production_...`. Make use the autocomplete. From [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#visibility):

  > Members of internal classes go through name mangling, to make it
  >   harder to accidentally use them from Java and to allow overloading for
  >   members with the same signature that don't see each other according to
  >   Kotlin rules;